# Multiprocessing: Two processes, kill both together

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, kill-process

I have two processes in a python programme, using the multiprocessing framework.
Each of them runs a function and each of them has a termination condition. If that happens, I want both to be killed.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array, Lock, Queue, active_children
import time
import random
from queue import Full

def producer_func(q:Queue, quantity):
    if condition:
       pass

def consumer_func(q:Queue, quantity, producer):
    if condition:
       producer.kill()

def main():
    q = Queue(10)
    quantity = 20

    producer = Process(name="producer", target=producer_func, args=(q, quantity))
    consumer = Process(name="consumer", target=consumer_func, args=(q, quantity, producer))

    producer.start()
    consumer.start()

    producer.join()
    consumer.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I can somehow kill the producer from the consumer, but I cannot do the same trick the other way around, since the consumer is not defined yet.
Is there a nice trick to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `multiprocess.Event`.

All workers should regularly check if this `Event` is set, and should return when it is.

The `Event` can be set from one of the workers or the parent.

```
def producer_func(q, quantity, condition):
    if condition.is_set():
       return

def consumer_func(q:Queue, quantity, producer, condition):
    if condition.is_set():
       return


def main():
    q = Queue(10)
    exit_event = multiprocessing.Event()
    quantity = 20

    producer = Process(name="producer", target=producer_func, args=(q, quantity, exit_event))
    consumer = Process(name="consumer", target=consumer_func, args=(q, quantity, exit_event))

    producer.start()
    consumer.start()

    producer.join()
    consumer.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```